# My 3D JavaScript game in PlayCanvas does nothing

Tags: javascript, playcanvas

I am in PlayCanvas and for the first time I'm making a 3d game. I tried to make a simple movement script but, with no errors in the code that I can see, it is not working.

I made this script:

```
var movement = pc.createScript('movement');

movement.attributes.add('speed', {type: 'number'});
movement.prototype.initialize = function() {
  console.log("Movement Activated")
};

movement.prototype.setMotion = function(dt) {
    // PC.KEY_W =>W
    //PC.KEY_TAB => TAB
    if (this.app.keyboard.isPressed(pc.KEY_W)){
        this.entity.rigidbody.applyForce( 
            0,
            0,
            1
        );
    }

};

movement.prototype.update = function(dt) {
    this.setMotion();
};
```

and it is definitely attached to the entity:

[image: It is attached]

but when I open the launch tab which lets me see what the game would be like for a player when I hit W nothing happens. If there are any errors please let me know.